# 'conda activate" is not working in git-bash shell But it looks well on cmd.exe

Tags: anaconda, git-bash

I am trying to make the virtual env. on my laptop

**using cmd terminal, I succeed well.
However, I stuck on a git-bash terminal.**

Do you know what is wrong?

Follows are the command I took on git-bash terminal.

1. conda info --envs

   1) base            *c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

   2) test            *c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test
2. activate test

   Then, output is "commandNotFoundError: No command 'conda conda'

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I had the `...No command 'conda conda'` error so I ran `conda update conda` to move from 4.6.11 to 4.6.14. Now I can activate my virt_env and I don't get that message.

Comment: Thank you. it works